# How to call a variable in a bash command line?

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I am trying to create this little program to help me, with only one command, to compile and run a C program within Ubuntu's terminal.

Trying to make it fancier, I added an argument to the bash file so I can use it for any C program I want. So this is how it is supposed to go:

- Create a variable to store the name of the file
- Use that variable to compile the program (to the same file name)
- Use that same name to run the file.

Here is the code:

```
# usr/bin/bash
filename=$1
cc -o $filename "$filename.c"
./$filename.out
```

almost everything runs, the only problem I still have is in the last line:

```
./$filename.out
```

It doesn't seem to use the name of the variable inside the command which executes the final program.

I'm a noob at bash (let's say I haven't used it in months).

Comment: I guess the **actual** problem is that your `cc` command doesn't produce `$filename.out` but just `$filename` -- that being said, a shell script doesn't make a good build tool. You should read up on Makefiles instead.

Answer (score 6):

`cc -o foo` will output `foo` not `foo.out`. You should also double-quote the variable expansions to prevent `IFS`-splitting and globbing:

```
filename=$1
cc -o "$filename" "$filename.c" &&
./"$filename"
```

Apart from that `# /usr/bin/bash` (unlike  `#!/usr/bin/bash`) does nothing. It's a comment. The whole thing will be run the `/bin/sh`, not `bash` (but you don't need bash, anyway).

Comment: I replaced `# /usr/bin/bash` by `#!/usr/bin/bash` and it didn't work as I expected. `bash: ./runC_Script.sh: usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Chihab although it doesn't matter because **you don't use any bash syntax** -- you didn't put `#!/usr/bin/bash` but `#!usr/bin/bash`. You should stop being so sloppy.

Comment: I gotta look into this, seems important!

Comment: @Chihab You might not have bash in `/usr/bin`. It could be in  `/bin`. I'd use `/bin/sh` (or `/bin/sh -e` to get aborts on failures by default) because it could be a much faster POSIX shell and a POSIX shell is all you need for this.

Comment: @Chihab as a general rule, prefer writing scripts with `#!/bin/sh` (they should therefore work with any `sh`-compatible shell and avoid *bashisms*). Only write `#!/usr/bin/bash` in scripts that **explicitly** need special bash syntax/features.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use quotation marks:

```
./"$filename.out"
```

Comment: This, although a good thing to do, is not necessary in every case. It definitely isn't the source of OP's problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=$1
cc -o "${filename}.out" "${filename}.c"
"./${filename}.out"
```

Comment: I could have used eval as well, still I needed to add `.out` in the first argument of `cc` as in `cc -o "$filename.out" "$filename.c"`

Thanks :D

Comment: You need to use ${var} syntax to concatinate string

Comment: `eval` is completely unnecessary here .. the best you could achieve is that it doesn't actively hurt.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, for single argument not necessary